# MAUI/Xamarin.iOS: How to let user pick a file to save now that documentPickerMode is deprecated?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, maui, mac-catalyst

I have tried going through StackOverflow and the [picker doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/document-picker). Unfortunately, all the answer for my need use `documentPickerMode` which is deprecated since iOS 14.

Looking at [Apple documentation on UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) I know I need to use `init(forExporting: [URL])`. However, I cannot find any similar binding in Xamarin.

My question is:

- How do I create such `UIDocumentPickerViewController`? I have successfully make a open dialog but not a save dialog.
- In the future, if I read Apple documentation, how can I find the equivalent class in C#? I do not know Swift well yet and apparently parameter name is part of their signature? In that case how does the Xamarin.iOS team translate it into C# considering there maybe multiple overloads with the same signature? Also I am assuming Swift `init` is C# constructor, is it correct?

Comment: *"How can I find the equivalent class in c#?"* The doc you link is for `Xamarin.iOS`, which is a C# representation of **iOS "native"** controls. (Now rebranded as `.Net 6 for iOS`.) Although `Xamarin.Forms` (and `Maui`) do convert **their cross-platform** controls into iOS controls, the API is not the same. That would be impossible, given that different platforms have different APIs. Are you writing an iOS-only UI, and want to use Apple APIs? OR are you writing cross-platform UI, and live with any limitations (compared to any single platform's API). This question is for which of those two?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I am using MAUI Blazor for UI. Right now there is no easy way to pick and save file for all platforms so I have been writing code for each. I have successfully written it for UWP and Android but I am not familiar with iOS/Mac API. So to answer your question, yes, I need this piece to be for platform-specific code (Xamarin iOS or any name they use now).

Answer (score 0):

google `xamarin ios UIDocumentPickerViewController` has link [.Net / .. / UIKit / UIDocumentPickerViewController Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uidocumentpickerviewcontroller?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12).

So far the class API documentation says `Xamarin.iOS`; so my comment above about rebranding to `.Net for iOS` is not relevant. Easier to find what you need as `xamarin`. TBD exactly what Microsoft will decide.

Usually the corresponding C# method is easily found. If not obvious from doc page, add Apple's method name to the google query:
`xamarin ios UIDocumentPickerViewController SOMEMETHODHERE`.

However, those `init...` methods Microsoft implements as `Constructors`; I think you want `UIDocumentPickerViewController(NSUrl, UIDocumentPickerMode)` on that page.